# Dagger Hilt: Repository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

Hilt points out that this interface cannot be provided without an @Provides annotation:

```
interface PlannedListRepository {
    fun getAllLists(): LiveData<List<PlannedList>>

    suspend fun addList(plannedList: PlannedList)

    suspend fun updateList(plannedList: PlannedList)

    suspend fun deleteList(plannedList: PlannedList)
}
```

Implementation of the interface:

```
class PlannedListRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val plannedListDao: PlannedListDao) :
    PlannedListRepository {
    ...
}
```

As far as I know, if I want to get an interface, I can use @Binds to say to Dagger which implementation should be received. So I did this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class RepositoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun providePlannedListRepository(impl: PlannedListRepositoryImpl) : PlannedListRepository
}
```

My ViewModel if it has something to deal with the error:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PlannedListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PlannedListRepository
    ) : ViewModel() {

    ...

}
```

So what should I do to fix the error? The full error message:

```
AndroidStudioProjects\PlanShopping\app\build\generated\hilt\component_sources\debug\com\tetsoft\planshopping\PlannerApplication_HiltComponents.java:129: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.tetsoft.planshopping.db.planned.PlannedListRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements PlannerApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
 com.tetsoft.planshopping.db.planned.PlannedListRepository is injected at
          com.tetsoft.planshopping.ui.planned.PlannedListViewModel(repository)
      com.tetsoft.planshopping.ui.planned.PlannedListViewModel is injected at
          com.tetsoft.planshopping.ui.planned.PlannedListViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.tetsoft.planshopping.PlannerApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.tetsoft.planshopping.PlannerApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.tetsoft.planshopping.PlannerApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

Here is the database module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) : PlannerDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            appContext,
            PlannerDatabase::class.java,
            "PlannerDB"
        )
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun providePlannedListDao(plannerDatabase: PlannerDatabase) : PlannedListDao {
        return plannerDatabase.plannedListDao()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideProductDao(plannerDatabase: PlannerDatabase) : ProductDao {
        return plannerDatabase.productDao()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideSelectedProductDao(plannerDatabase: PlannerDatabase) : SelectedProductDao {
        return plannerDatabase.selectedProductDao()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)` in your repository module since you are injection repository in your view model

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it didn't help. The same error pops up.

Comment: Have you provided PlannedListDao via @Provides annotation ?

Comment: I updated my question with DatabaseModule to clarify that.

Comment: @Corec Muhammed's answer should be right: Note that ViewModelComponent is not in the same [hierarchy](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components) as ActivityComponent, but rather ActivityRetainedComponent. It would make sense that your RepositoryModule isn't helping with bindings in your ViewModel, and that changing RepositoryModule's `@InstallIn` to either ViewModelComponent or ActivityRetainedComponent would solve your problem.

Comment: @JeffBowman yeah, you are right. For some reason, previous builds had a different error that I've mentioned in the topic. For now, it says `may not reference bindings with different scopes` if I'm going with either ViewModelComponent or ActivityRetainedComponent. Is it a bad practice if I use SingletonComponent for my RepositoryModule?

Comment: @Corec Ah, yeah, scope mismatch is a different problem that indicates this answer got you further along. I tend to think Singleton scope is perfectly reasonable for repositories so you can reuse data and caches from multiple Activities, but shorter can be better in general since it means you can garbage collect objects when the Activity finishes. If you keep too many Singletons without thinking about memory usage, then the only option you give Android is to kill your app entirely when the user switches apps and memory pressure increases. Doesn't mean Singleton is wrong, just be careful.

Comment: @JeffBowman big thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never.

Besides you need do the thing mentioned in the accepted answer.If you are working with compose or the latest Hilt version, init your ViewModel by the way of:

`val viewModel: YourViewModel by viewModels()`

do not use the way of:

`@Inject lateinit var viewModel: YourViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

Is your application multi modules? If your answer is yes check your imports from your :app, in my case I facing the same error and I forgot to add my other modules where he DI was defined!

Comment: My man, I can't thank you enough